# How do I return value at the end of iteration on list using lambda, Java

Tags: list, lambda, java-8

Trying to iterate over a list of Objects to get the value of the last parameter from the iteration.

```
long lastSeen = 0L;
for(Object o : list) {
    lastSeen = o.getLastSeenId();
}
// will make use of the lastSeen.
```

I cant do the same with lambda,

```
long lastSeen = 0L;
list.stream().forEach(o-> {
    lastSeen = o.getLastSeenId();
});
```

as I will end with this compile-time.

> Local variable lastSeenId defined in an enclosing scope must be final
>   or effectively final

I could do this to read the largest, but don't want to:

```
Set<Long> set = new HashSet<>();
list.stream().forEach(o-> {
    set.add(mergeUser.getLastSeenId());
});
```

Is there a better way? 
Reason to do this is to monitor the last seen value loop processed(if in case of an exception occurred to terminate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you need to iterate the entire source to just to retrieve the last id. This could be accomplish without iteration:

```
long lastSeen = list.size() > 0? list.get(list.size()-1).getLastSeenId() : 0L;
```

However, if you plan to do some other stuff in each iteration not just the aforementioned then I'd stick with your current imperative approach. Attempting to use streams here is not a good fit and doesn't gain you anything.

Comment: I'm doing the same as of now. Loop is not just to find the lastId, also performing some database action in the loop.

Comment: @srikanth In which case my last paragraph is your best option. using streams is not a good fit for it.

Comment: `! list.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

First `reduce` the set of elements to get the last element from the `Stream`. Then use `map` to get the desired value from the last element after the reduction.

```
final long lastSeenValue = objects.stream()
    .reduce((first, second) -> second)
    .map(LastSeen::getLastSeenId)
    .orElse(null);
```

However in my opinion, streams might not be a better choice for your problem statement. In that case don't hesitate to fall back to imperative approach.

Comment: I thought about that, but the OP said the reason for this requirement is to know the last value that was processed in case of exception. If there is an exception during the Stream processing, there would be no value produced by the Stream pipeline, would there?

Comment: Yes unfortunately that part is not handled in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to keep using `Stream`, you may use `AtomicLong` to hold the *lastSeenValue*.

```
final AtomicLong lastSeen = new AtomicLong(0);
list.stream().forEach(o-> {
    lastSeen.set(o.getLastSeenId());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not iterate the list for fetching the last element.

If in case, if you want to stream and get the last element, "one.util.StreamEx" has a better way to do that:

```
StreamEx.of(list)
            .collect(MoreCollectors.last())
            .get();
```

Comment: ah. Just read the last line your question. this may not solve that.